# XSL translate wrong output

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a problem with translating a text!

```
<text>This is a non breaking -</text>
<text>
    <span style="">
        <span style="">Testtext</span>
    </span>
    ‑
    <span style="">
        <span style=""> some other text</span>
    </span>
</text>
```

this is the .xml file I get from the ck editor and in between the spans I have an non-breaking hyphen, but arial can not display this non-breaking hyphen in my .pdf file. I'm not allowed to change the font of the .pdf so I'd like to translate the non-breaking hyphen to a 'normal' hyphen.

```
<xsl:template match="text">
        <fo:block>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="not(*) and contains(text(), '&#8209;')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="translate(text(), '&#8209;' , '-')"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:if test="contains(text(), '&#8209;')"> <!-- Here is my problem -->
                        <xsl:value-of select="translate(text(), '&#8209;' , '-')"/>
                        <xsl:apply-templates />
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="not(contains(text(), '&#8209;'))"> 
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

now my problem is, after the `if` with the comment `here is my problem`, when I don't apply the templates before this is the output:

```
This is a non breaking - //thats ok
-Testtext# some other text //thats not
```

but if I aplly them them the `<xsl:value-of select=....` doesn't work.

it should look like this:

```
This is a non breaking -
Testtext- some other text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid selecting a sequence of more than one item by `text()` (I think this is causing the malfunction here), you could try to apply the translate function directly on the text nodes, like this:

```
<xsl:template match="text//text()[contains(.,'&#8209;')]">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '&#8209;' , '-')"/>
</xsl:template>
```